# I have a fresh VirtualServer running Ubuntu 12.04, how do I get a LAMP server running?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php5, installation

Although I have an overview of running commands like `apt-get install apache2` what I don't know is what order I should run them in to get a LAMP server running.

Also, I assume I should create a `/var/www` to put my sites in there (want about 4 domains pointing to this server.

As I have a clean slate, would be great to get advice on the correct way to get set up.

(as a side note, I want to replicate these settings in vagrant/puppet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very easy way to do this in Ubuntu, run the command

```
sudo tasksel
```

It will provide you a list of items to install, scroll down to LAMP and press the space bar to select it, then press enter, it will install all the pre-requisites required and it will all be preconfigured.

Comment: `tasksel: aptitude failed (100)`? :-(

Answer (score 1):

1. Install apache ( sudo apt-get install apache2 ) and test the results http://website.name
2. Install PHP5 ( sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 ) - restart apache2 ( /etc/init.d/apache2 restart ) - create under /var/www/website.name a file named test.php with the following code in it "" ; test with http://website.name/test.php
3. Install mysql ( sudo apt-get install mysql-server); dont forget to set a root password ( mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('YourPasswordHere'); )

Comment: thanks - sounds simple enough! But what about things like ```mysql-client``` ?

Comment: You can install mysql-client along with mysql-server.